Saving Hashmap of Player and an Integer
I want to save a Hashmap to a file:
public static Map<Player, Integer> seconds = new HashMap<>();

It is to keep track of an integer given to a player, more specifically a timer.
This is all working, but when the player leaves, the data is lost which is an issue.
I don't mind how it is saved, I just need it to be saved on player quit and retrieved when the player joins.
P.S. I am new to plugin development (and Java I guess), and I really have done as much research as possible but no luck with this problem.
I tried countless methods, such as:

Saving to JSON with GSON (and other methods)
I Looked into the Serializable class.

I wanted the file to be saved somewhere in the server.
When a player leaves, the current Integer value must be saved to the Player.
When a player joins, the Player's Integer will load and resume where it left off.

Do you want to use basic spigot config file or specific file ? Also, can you show the code you tried ?

I suggest using a MySQL Database for such actions, HirakiCP is a great option for Java to connect to a MySQL Database. You could just create a table with 2 columns, one for the Players UUID and one for the Integer.

The class you want is YamlConfiguration. When you start your plugin, You should create a File instance.
File timerFile = new File("plugins/YourPluginName", "timers.yml");
if(!timerFile.exists) timerFile.createNewFile();
YamlConfiguration cfg = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(timerFile);

Now that you have this YamlConfiguration, you can write values to it, and to relate it back to the player, you simply save it by UUID.
cfg.set(player.getUniqueId().toString(), timerSeconds);
cfg.save(timerFile);

When the player joins, simply set the timer back to its saved value by checking if the players UUID exists in the file.
String UUID = player.getUniqueId().toString();
if(cfg.get(UUID) != null) timerSeconds = cfg.getInt(UUID);

Also, before I leave you off to go back to your work, you should know as a new Java Programmer, that JavaDocs are your friend. You can look into the JavaDocs of Spigot anytime to find what you may be looking for. Good luck, and happy Developing!
